# What changed about syntax highlighting (in template literals) since Atom 1.32.0?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, updates, atom-editor, template-literals

For months I had highlighting of SQL code inside template literals in my js file working **without** [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel) installed, but with [language-sql](https://atom.io/packages/language-sql) installed in Atom.

Today I updated Atom to 1.32.0 and now no more SQL highlighting inside template literals.

I followed https://github.com/gandm/language-babel#javascript-tagged-template-literal-grammar-extensions to fix this. But I wondered why it has been working without having language-babel installed all that time.

Anyway, I installed [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel) and added `"(?:css\.(?:[a-z])+)":source.css, /* @html */:text.html.basic, sql:source.sql` inside the settings of language-babel. But it had no effect. Restarting Atom did not help either.
[image]

What changed about syntax highlighting (in template literals) since Atom 1.32.0?

Comment: Try command `Set syntax: Babel ES6 JavaScript`, i.e. ensure that you are using the expected syntax.

Comment: But why? I never did that before and syntax highlighting **was** working.

Comment: Some glitch. The only reason I know is because I came across the same behaviour after the upgrade.

Comment: What! It worked. Thanks. I'm not sure though if installing language-babel was necessary.